# IMU software-based Orientation Adjustment

Tags: math, embedded, orientation, imu

I have a six-axis IMU that outputs orientation data in Quaternion, Euler angle, and YPR formats. This data is used in a quadcopter PID controller for stabilization.

I have built a test stand for tuning the quadcopter; however, the axis of rotation for the test stand is ~45° rotated from the IMU measurement axes.

Previously, I managed to adjust the offset using a rotation matrix, but (given some changes to the program) I am now dealing with angles/quaternions instead of vectors, and it seems that this method is no longer applicable (at least without intermediate steps) to the measurement data.

This leads to my question: How can I apply this 45° transformation to the output data (in the provided format-- quaternion, Euler, YPR) in order to measure the attitude along the axis of rotation?

Comment: Does this answer the question? https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1499415/finding-the-quaternion-that-performs-a-rotation

Comment: Sounds like a math problem, not a programming problem.

Comment: @SeverinPappadeux yes! Very helpful. Thank you.